# Get a single word after or before a match?

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

The input is

```
aa bb cc color:red dd ee ff
```

And my RegEx is

```
:
```

How can I get the color before the colon or red after the colon?

I only want the first single word before or after the colon.

Comment: please share your efforts !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with capturing groups: [`(\w+)(?:\:)(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/SmdBJ9/1)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\w+)(?:\:)(\w+)";
        string input = @"aa bb cc color:red dd ee ff";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' full math at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
            Console.WriteLine("Capture group 1: '{0}'", m.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Capture group 2: '{0}'", m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
'color:red' full math at index 9.
Capture group 1: 'color'
Capture group 2: 'red'
```

PS: You do not need to escape the literal colon, I just did it to make the pattern more readable.

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thanks! Btw, I'm just wondering, what is the use of @ in regex?

Comment: This is not regex specific. The @ makes it a [verbatim string](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean/)